Assumptions Wald's second equation?
Let $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be an i.i.d. sequence of random variables and $N$ an $\mathbb{N}_0$ valued random variable. Let $X_1 \in \mathcal{L}^2$ and $N \in \mathcal{L}^1$. Let $S_n := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and $\sigma^2:= \text{Var}(X_1), \ \mu:= \mathbb{E}[X_1]$. Wald's second equation reads
$$\mathbb{E}[(S_N - N\mu)^2] = \sigma^2\mathbb{E}[N]$$
It holds if $N$ is a stopping time w.r.t. to the natural filtration.
Now I have seen that it should also hold, if one only requires that $(X_k)_{k \geq n+1}$ and $\{N=n\}$ are independent for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$. Is this true?
The proof works if it is true that $\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_{k-1}, \{N=0\},\dots, \{N=k-1\})$ and $X_k$ are independent for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Why should this be true?
By the assumptions one knows that $X_k$ and $\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_{k-1})$ are independent and also $X_k$ and $\{N=l\}$ for all $l=0,\dots,k-1$ (pairwise, individually). But why does it follow that $\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_{k-1}, \{N=0\},\dots, \{N=k-1\})$ and $X_k$ are independent, so jointly?

I suppose one way to think about it is that the sigma algebra you wrote is contained in the filtration $\mathcal{F}{k-1}$ and this is independent of the law of $X{k}$.

@ThomasKojar If $N$ was a stopping time this would hold. But in the second I don't assume that $N$ is a stopping time w.r.t. the natural filtration but only that $(X_k)_{k \geq n+1}$ and ${N=n}$ are independent ($N$ being arbitrary otherwise). So, in particular, there is a priori no filtration.

it's still should be ok, just augment by the filtration of your Ns.

@ThomasKojar Yes, that is what I want to show, that the augmented sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}{k-1} = \sigma(X_1,...,X{k-1}, {N=0},...,{N=k-1})$ is independent of $X_k$. Why is this true? There is no $\cap$-stable generator or so that it follows jointly independence?

unless I am misunderstanding, this is standard using Dynkin's pi-system theorem but for just two random variables i.e. using the independence of $Y_{1}=(X_i, N=i){i=1,...,k}$ and $Y{2}=X_{k}$, their corresponding sigma-algebras will be independent also.

@ThomasKojar I mean for all fixed (but arbitrary) $n$ we only assume $(X_k){k \geq n+1}$ and ${N = n}$ are independent. Now fix $k \in \mathbb{N}$. How can I follow that $X_k$ is independent of the sigma algebra $\sigma(X_1,...,X{k-1}, {N=0},...{N=k-1})$ (i.e. $X_k$ is simultaneously independent of $X_1,...,X_{k-1}$ and ${N=0},...,{N=k-1}$)?

so lets fix $k=10$, then your assumption says that $X_{10}$ is independent of $N=9$. But if we put $n=8$, then it also says that $X_{10}$ is independent of $N=8$. And so on and so forth.

@ThomasKojar Right. But then we only know this pairwise. Now, why are they all independent? Maybe I am missing something really stupid. There exist random variables which are pairwise independent but not jointly, don't there? What you wrote is what I meant with the last paragraph of the original question.

I see what your question is now. Yes, I agree that condition seem strange because you will ideally want independence with all N=9,N=8,... Can I see the reference and I can try to get their proof? They are probably doing the reverse of what I just did i.e. using that N=n is independent of the joint X_n+1,....

@ThomasKojar I only have it handwritten. In the proof it is used to show that $M_n := \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)1_{N\geq i}$ ($n\in \mathbb{N_0}$) defines an $\mathcal{L}^2$-martingale with $\mathbb{E}[M_n^2] = \sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(N \geq i) \to \sigma^2 \mathbb{E}[N]$ for $n \to \infty$. Then a convergence theorem for martingales is used to conclude that $M_n$ converges to $S_N - \mu N$ in $L^2$.

you mention that you saw that condition somewhere, can you include some reference? For example, here https://math.dartmouth.edu/~pw/math100w13/hein.pdf they mention that condition but they also assume that N is a stopping time.
